# Why ng-show doesn't work when F or N is typed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AnguarJS and there is something I don't understand about ng-show.

I have the following code: http://codepen.io/mars16/full/atGLp

When the user starts to type in the input field, I expect a colon to appear followed by whatever is typed. I have noticed that when f or n is typed in initially the colon character doesn't appear till more letters are typed in. Why is this?

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that angular considers the values 'f', 'false', '0', 'n', and 'no' to be falsy! There is [an open bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3436) for this behavior. You can fix it with sza's approach, or you can also do this:

```
<span ng-show="!!variable.one">:</span>
```

Comment: More of a feature than a bug though. For this reason I would always recommend using strict checks for conditions.

Comment: Yep, it's just understanding that's how javascript natively work.  If you wrap it the content of ng-show in an if statement, then it would result in the same thing.  That's why you need to check like sza.

Comment: This is the stupidest thing I've seen in a popular framework. First of all 'f', 'no', and 'n' have no business being falsy. Also there strings. JavaScript does not work this way natively, or else '!!' wouldn't work. In native JavaScript a string with any content is a truthy value. What actually happens is that if angular detects that the value of an expression is a string, it evals the it again. This is useless, and causes more issues than its word. Things that are simply "cool" don't have any place in a framework, and Angular is full of them.

Comment: It definitely does not conform to the "principle of least astonishment!" :)

Answer (score 2):

The criterion doesn't look correct, [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow) should take a `boolean` type. Try this

```
<span ng-show="variable.one.length > 0">:</span>
```